# How to use indexers in switch expression?

Tags: c#, switch-expression, property-pattern

How to access indexers in switch expression? There is a nice [property pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern) syntax in [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression#case-guards), but I can't figure out or find any information about using indexers.

Given following code:

```
var a = "123";
if(a.Length == 3 && a[0] == '1')
    Console.WriteLine("passed");
```

How do to convert it to switch expression? Matching `a.Length` is easy, but how to specify a match for `a[0] == '1'`?

```
var b = a switch
{
    { Length: 3, this[0]: '1' } => "passed", // CS8918: Identifier or a simple member access expected.
    _ => "error"
};
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AioafV).

Comment: => https://dotnetfiddle.net/CeqiOG ? `['1', _, _] => "passed"` == exactly 3 elements, of which the first is '1' and the other two I don't care about. But that's _not_ using indexers, of course.

Comment: You can use a [list pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#list-patterns) with containers but this is really string matching. You can put that condition in a `when` clause. `{Length: 3} s when s[0]=='1'`. Or use a regular expression

Comment: Are you trying to create a parser?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, smart, so the `Length` is also implicitly checked.

Comment: Yes. But I somehow missed, that you _want_ to use an indexer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, not a parser, just simplifying some code (multiple `if/else`) and learning new stuff. Solution with  `when` works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Requiring a fixed length with a specific first letter sounds a lot like part of a mini parser. You could come up with simpler and faster code if you look at the overall syntax and use some parser techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is by using `when` [statement](https://ochzhen.com/blog/switch-case-when-in-csharp). It is not as beautiful as property pattern, but can be a workaround:

```
var b = a switch
{
    { Length: 3 } when a[0] == '1' => "passed",
    _ => "error"
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am limited by C# 9.0 atm. I am going to use your solution. `['1', _, _]`-solution requires at least 11.0. =/

Answer (score 4):

Since C# 11 you can use [list patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/list-patterns):

```cs
var b = a switch
{
    ['1', _, _] => "passed", // CS8918: Identifier or a simple member access expected.
    _ => "error"
};
```

Comment: I like this answer the most, makes code very clean. Also flexible, to example: `['1', _, _] or ['1', _] when a[1] == '2' => "passed"` . But it's too specific to `Length` check and I want to stay on topic, just to use indexers is done by using `when`.

Comment: @Sinatr @Sinatr the second one would be simply `['1', '2']` or just `"12" => ...`, if you want check with any length then you can do `[_,'2', ..]` - this will check for string with 2 in second position and length >= 2.